# Flashing target with GHS probe using command line

Tags: embedded, greenhills, coldfire

We're using Greenhills Multi IDE and [Greenhills Debug Probe](https://www.ghs.com/products/probe.html) to program and debug our target system (a Coldfire based, bare metal system). Currently I flash the target using the IDE debugger GUI, but I would prefer to use a command line interface to do it.

The documentation is fairly sketchy, and only gives a very simple example. As far as I can tell I should be able to use grun with gflash to do this, but I'm having a hard time figuring out which GUI fields map to which grun options. Anyone with any experience of this?

[image]

Basically I need to be able to specify (see image above):

Flash device (this one I've got figured out I think)

- Base address
- Image file (we use raw images)
- Offset in flash
- Alternate RAM base
- Alternate flash utility
- Possibly also alternate MBS script

Any tips, tricks, or pointers to better documentation than the standard GHS one? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: You pay not a small amount of money for the tools, so one could expect their support to be the first place to ask.

Comment: Sounds like production programming...? If so, you'll probably want some other tool for that. Like... a stand-alone production programmer.

Comment: Please check the GHS documentation. It is not freely available so i cannot give any further information.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Indeed, and I may have to go through the official support, but experience is that it's nearly always faster to check with other users first

Comment: @Lundin No, we're not at production stage yet, it's just that being able to script this would make my life that much easier.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I have access to the documentation, but as mentioned above it's not particularly forthcoming on this subject. Or do you have a specific reference to the appropriate section in the docs?

Comment: @BjornRudolfsson Surely their debugger must support some manner of custom scripting without needing command line for it?

Comment: Inm that case you should consider using free of charge tools like OpenOCV and the gnu tools. I'm not sure. The compiler supports ColdFire, not sure about OpenOCV, but I well know you can script that excellently directly or indirectly (via Telnet or gdb-server protocol) with little effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is below screenshot from debugger command reference is of any help? You can use it to download your source on HW. I will be able to share more details is this helps. Or you can share your solution if you had already found it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I was after. I will try it out.

Comment: Took me a while to get round to it, but I have managed to confirm this works fine, albeit only from the debugger window. Many thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a flag for adding banks via the command line. Does anyone know if there is a way to flash to multiple flash banks from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I used `mpadmin` for this purpose.

```
mpadmin -update <IP-addr_of_your-probe | -usb> firmware.frm
```